# How can I keep an item collapsed in org-mode when emacs starts?

Tags: org-mode

I have multiple items in my `org-mode`, example:

```
* work                       wanted behavior when emacs startup
** item_1                  | ** item_1
Notes ...                  | ** item_2
** item_2                  | Notes...
Notes...                   |
```

my setup:

```
(require 'org)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (local-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'org-show-subtree)))
```

When I restart emacs all show up as expanded. Would it be possible to keep selected ones collapsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `VISIBILITY` property of an entry:

```org
* work   
** item_1
:PROPERTIES:
:VISIBILITY: folded
:END:
   Notes

** item_2
:PROPERTIES:
:VISIBILITY: all
:END:
Notes
```

See the "Initial Visibility" section of the manual: `C-h i g(org)initial visibility`.

Comment: Is `:END:` required to be added?

Comment: Still all shown unfolded :-( Should I also disable `org-show-subtree` ?

Comment: Did you kill the buffer and reopen the file? This controls *initial* visibility only.

Comment: Yes, `:END:` is part of the drawer (any drawer, not just a properties drawer), but it gets inserted automatically if you create the properties drawer with `C-c C-x p`.

Comment: Yes I killed the buffer and emacs and re-open it. But everthing stills unfolded (not sure why) . Could `org-show-subtree` force to unfold all items?

Comment: Try with `emacs -q`: you probably have something else that interacts with this.

Comment: In order for this to work, you can add this to your file: ```#+STARTUP: showall```